# Symfony Twig variable is null error on Inspect, but still working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've an array for static texts. I'm sending this array variable every html.twig file on render.

```
return $this->render("product.html.twig", array(
        "staticText" =>  $this->staticText,
    ));
```

My "product.html twig" is extending from base.html.twig
Also in `base.html.twig` im calling `{{staticText["xx"]}}`

But when i load `product.html.twig` there is an error in inspect->network:

> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/e21a38/
>       Key "xx" does not exist as the array is empty.

I do not understand i'm getting this error on Inspect but everything is working well.
I've tried to escape from this error like

```
{% if staticText is defined %} - {% if staticText[0] is defined %}
```

It is worked on start, but this time my all css and js files loaded twice.

Sorry for my English, i hope u can understand me.
Am i building twig wrong? Maybe base html is loading first and can't see {{ staticText }} variable. But i've tried to make "staticText" variable as global twig variable according to this [symfony twig global variable](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html), got the same error

Comment: Your test `defined` will not work as an `empty` array is considered defined. U'd need to use the test `is empty` or `{{ staticText['xx'] | default('') }}`

Comment: @DarkBee it is not a bad solution. How can i made this with defeault? {{ path('index', { 'country': country.code, 'language': lang.code }) }}

Comment: @DarkBee  when i tried to use  {{ staticText['xx'] | default('') }}, the error has gone, but now it says country.code on null error. i've tried to do {% if country.code defined%} the error has gone, but all css and js files loading twice :S

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by closing Symfony Profiler. I do not know it's a correct solution, but it solved mine.